# How to retrieve the branch where a commit was created originally using LibGit2Sharp?

Tags: c#, git, libgit2sharp

how can I retrieve the branch where a commit was created originally using LibGit2Sharp?
Assumed that I have two branches (development, feature1 ) which have several commits and are merged some time later. When I retrieve all commits and the branches they are belonging every commit is linked with the two branches. So it is not possible to determine which is the original source branch.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git does not store any such information, which means it is not retrievable, no matter what access method you use.

Branch *names* are largely ephemeral and can be created and destroyed whenever you like, with one caveat: a commit that is not reachable by *any* name is subject to garbage-collection.  But if a commit *C* is reachable from branch names *B1, B2, B3* then commit *C* is contained within all three branches.  Remove name *B2* and commit *C* is now contained within branches *B1* and *B3*.

(The name that protects a commit need not be a *branch* name.  A tag name, or a `stash` reference, or a remote-tracking branch name, or any other name anywhere in the `refs` name-space, suffices to protect a commit.  [This is not a complete list but covers all the normal reliable cases.]  This rule applies recursively to all other protected commits as well: if commit *C* is reachable from protected commit *P*, then *C* is also protected, and *C* in turn protects all commits reachable from *C*.)

Comment: Thanks for that explanation.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not possible... 
Git branches are pointers and branch name is not written in commit metadata. Once moved, you can't figure out the past (with git nor libgit2sharp).

A solution is perhaps to parse the branches reflog if the lines concerning the commit is still in there, are not too old and been removed from the logs files.

But I don't understand such a need. Generally, that's the present that is useful. In witch branches is the commit.

Perhaps a bad versioning strategy? Storing the commit Shaw when releasing is a mutch better idea....